OOM issue on partition shuffling
Given

Spark jobs are running on Kubernetes cluster
executor pod has 4 cores
there is java process with the params (-Xms3072m, -Xmx3072m) running in executor pod
there is ORC file in AWS S3 of ~5MB with 3652 records, every record has 2419 columns
OOM of executors trying to run the below Spark SQL.

The flow

Reading the ORC into Dataframe
Rename almost all columns
Making projection the columns into column with name value which is json {"schema": [{"field1", "optional": false, "type": "string"}, ...], "payload": {"field1": "val1", "field2": "val2", ...}}
Create 5 partitions
Write partitioned data into ORC files on S3.

Codebase
    val dataframe = spark
          .read
          .format("orc")
          .load(inputS3Path)

    val dfCols = dataFrame.columns.map(colName => col(s"$colName"))

    val payloadStruct = struct(dfCols: _*)

    val connectSchema = prepareConnectSchema(dataFrame.schema)

    dataframe
        .withColumn("schema", from_json(lit(connectSchema), schema_of_json(connectSchema)))
        .withColumn("payload", payloadStruct)
        .withColumn("value", to_json(struct(col("schema"), col("payload"))))
        .select(col("value"))
        .repartition(5)
        .withColumn("_partition_column", concat_ws("_", lit("project-1"), lit(spark_partition_id())))
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .partitionBy("_partition_column")
        .orc(outputS3Path)

  def prepareSchema(structType: StructType): String = {
    val schema = buildConnectSchema(structType)
    val jsonConverter = new JsonConverter()
    jsonConverter.configure(Collections.singletonMap("schemas.enable", false), false)
    val jsonNode = jsonConverter.asJsonSchema(schema)
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode)
  }

  def buildSchema(structType: StructType): Schema = {
    val builder = new SchemaBuilder(STRUCT)
    structType.foreach(field => {
      field.dataType match {
        case subStructType: StructType => val intermediateSchema = buildSchema(subStructType)
          builder.field(field.name, intermediateSchema)
        case arrayType: ArrayType => val intermediateSchema = SchemaBuilder.array(buildValueSchemaForArrayType(arrayType))
          builder.field(field.name, intermediateSchema)
        case _ => builder.field(field.name, mapToKafkaType(field.dataType))
      }
    })
    builder.build()
  }  

The execution plan.
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (13)
+- == Current Plan ==
   Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand (8)
   +- WriteFiles (7)
      +- Sort (6)
         +- Project (5)
            +- ShuffleQueryStage (4)
               +- Exchange (3)
                  +- Project (2)
                     +- Scan orc  (1)
+- == Initial Plan ==
   Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand (12)
   +- WriteFiles (11)
      +- Sort (10)
         +- Project (9)
            +- Exchange (3)
               +- Project (2)
                  +- Scan orc  (1)

(1) Scan orc 
Output [2419]: [field1#0, field2#1, ...]
Batched: false
Location: InMemoryFileIndex [s3://s3-path]
ReadSchema: struct<field1:string, field2:string, ...>

(2) Project
Output [1]: [to_json((ignoreNullFields,true), struct(schema, [[[field1,null,false,int32,null],[field2,null,false,string,null], ...],false,struct], payload, struct(field1, field1#0, field2, field2#1, ...)) AS value#48481]
Input [2419]: [field1#0, field2#1, ...]

(3) Exchange
Input [1]: [value#48481]
Arguments: RoundRobinPartitioning(5), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [plan_id=72]

(4) ShuffleQueryStage
Output [1]: [value#48481]
Arguments: 0

(5) Project
Output [2]: [value#48481, concat_ws(_, project-1, cast(SPARK_PARTITION_ID() as string)) AS _partition_column#50921]
Input [1]: [value#48481]

(6) Sort
Input [2]: [value#48481, _partition_column#50921]
Arguments: [_partition_column#50921 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0

(7) WriteFiles
Input [2]: [value#48481, _partition_column#50921]

(8) Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand
Input: []
Arguments: s3://output-path/], Overwrite, [value, _partition_column]

(9) Project
Output [2]: [value#48481, concat_ws(_, project-1, cast(SPARK_PARTITION_ID() as string)) AS _partition_column#50921]
Input [1]: [value#48481]

(10) Sort
Input [2]: [value#48481, _partition_column#50921]
Arguments: [_partition_column#50921 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0

(11) WriteFiles
Input [2]: [value#48481, _partition_column#50921]

(12) Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand
Input: []
Arguments: s3://output-path/], Overwrite, [value, _partition_column]

(13) AdaptiveSparkPlan
Output: []
Arguments: isFinalPlan=false


Spark UI


Thoughts

I'm suspecting that the OOM issue could be related to executor's Peak JVM memory Onheap and Peak Execution memory Onheap which sum (3GB + 1.2GB) is greater than 3GB allocated for JVM (-Xms3072m, -Xmx3072m).

On the other hand, Spark UI summary shows that memory is not exceeded.


I'm not sure that I understand the numbers correctly.


The question: how to fix the OOM issue?
